# How do I implement BN_num_bytes() (and BN_num_bits() ) in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, openssl, biginteger

I'm [porting this line from C++ to C#,](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bignum.h#L310) and I'm not an experienced C++ programmer:

```
 unsigned int nSize = BN_num_bytes(this);
```

In .NET I'm [using System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8100/1878)

```
 BigInteger num = originalBigNumber;
 byte[] numAsBytes = num.ToByteArray();
 uint compactBitsRepresentation = 0;
 uint size2 = (uint)numAsBytes.Length;
```

I think there is a fundamental difference in how they operate internally, since [the sources' unit tests' results](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8046/1878) don't match if the BigInt equals:

- 0
- Any negative number
- 0x00123456

I know literally nothing about `BN_num_bytes` (*edit: the comments just told me that it's  a macro for BN_num_bits)*.

**Question**

Would you verify these guesses about the code:

- I need to port `BN_num_bytes` which is a macro for `((BN_num_bits(bn)+7)/8)` (Thank you @WhozCraig)
- I need to port `BN_num_bits` which is `floor(log2(w))+1`

Then, if the possibility exists that leading and trailing bytes aren't counted, then what happens on Big/Little endian machines?  Does it matter?

Based on [these answers on Security.StackExchange,](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31979/396) and that my application isn't performance critical, I may use the default implementation in .NET  and not use an alternate library that may already implement a comparable workaround.

---

Edit: so far my implementation looks something like this, but I'm not sure what the "LookupTable" is as mentioned in the comments.

```
   private static int BN_num_bytes(byte[] numAsBytes)
    {
        int bits = BN_num_bits(numAsBytes);
        return (bits + 7) / 8; 
    }

    private static int BN_num_bits(byte[] numAsBytes)
    {
        var log2 = Math.Log(numAsBytes.Length, 2);
        var floor = Math.Floor(log2);
        return (uint)floor + 1;
    }
```

---

Edit 2:

After some more searching, [I found that:](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mailing.unix.openssh-dev/DDGOu6w9_7c)

> BN_num_bits does not return the number of significant bits of a given bignum, but rather the position of the most significant 1 bit, which is not necessarily the same thing

Though I still don't know what the source of it looks like...

Comment: FWIW, BN_ looks like part of a bignum library.

Comment: `BN_num_bytes()` is a macro wrapper around `BN_num_bits()`, literally `((BN_num_bits(bn)+7)/8)`. Just that alone tells me only the number of significant bits is used in the computation. I.e. the value `1` would, by the lookup table in `BN_num_bits()` has only one significant bit, therefore one significant byte, regardless of how "large" the leading zero-bits extend in the MSB lineage.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can a C++ lookup table (and the corresponding macro) be implemented in C#? Perhaps as an array?

Comment: @makerofthings7: Are you using .NET's BigInteger?

Comment: @leppie Yes [my implementation is here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8100/1878) .. the problem function is at the top of the Q (second half)... Get Compact

Comment: @makerofthings7: `BN_num_bytes` should be the same as `BigInteger.ToByteArray().Length`

Comment: @leppie I would test each unit test in C++, but I only know I have VC++ installed. (not sure what project type to choose to create, debug, and test it).  I suspect C++ `BN_num_bytes()` of a bigNumber = 0 has a size of zero... while C# offers a size of 1 for BigInteger.  If this is true, I suspect additional variations.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Have you looked at an alternative bignum library? I use IntX. It is opensource, so you can get into the guts of it ;p

Comment: @Leppie Never heard of IntX.  Just looked it up and they say it's no longer being developed, and it's still faster than .Net4's BigInteger with FHT!!.. but GMP is the best for speed.  Should I use GMP with .NET?  Is one better for OpenCL than the other?  (I want to offload to a GPU, FPGA in the future)

Comment: @makerofthings7: IntX is stable, it needs no more development :) I looked at GMP, but it seems to be a PITA. Have no idea about the GPGPU stuff ;p

Comment: Why do you need to know about the internal representation of a bigint?  What are you trying to do with it?  What does it not do that you hope to accomplish with the number of bytes used by the representation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_num_bytes.html) (OpenSSL project) of BN_num_bits says that "Basically, except for a zero, it returns `floor(log2(w))+1`.".
So these are the correct implementations of the `BN_num_bytes` and `BN_num_bits` functions for .Net's `BigInteger`.

```
public static int BN_num_bytes(BigInteger number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + (int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log(BigInteger.Abs(number), 2)) / 8;
}

public static int BN_num_bits(BigInteger number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + (int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log(BigInteger.Abs(number), 2));
}
```

You should probably change these into extension methods for convenience.

You should understand that these functions measure the minimum number of bits/bytes that are needed to express a given integer number. Variables declared as `int` (`System.Int32`) take 4 bytes of memory, but you only need 1 byte (or 3 bits) to express the integer number 7. This is what BN_num_bytes and BN_num_bits calculate - the minimum required storage size for a concrete number.

You can find the source code of the original implementations of the functions in the [official OpenSSL repository](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob_plain;f=crypto/bn/bn_lib.c;hb=HEAD).

Comment: The man page is actually wrong and it should be floor(log2(w+1)). Next time just put your correction in the comments please.

Comment: @mattmanser There is nothing wrong with the manual. More so, the `floor(log2(w))+1` is more correct since it works for many different number types. Meanwhile your function doesn't even work for unsigned integers. My "number of bits" function `floor(log2(w)) + 1` rises when `w >= 2^k`, while your `ceiling(log2(w+1))` rises when `w > 2^k - 1`. I like the former behavior better.

Comment: Dude, you copied my code, your code was still wrong and you did it all for internet points. I'm baffled by your reaction. 'My function' is the function you copied and then edited to pretend you didn't. You even copied my function name then changed it to pretend you didn't! What is wrong with you? I was just trying to be nice and help makerofthings7 out, why did you have to spoil it? Your 'better' code didn't work. Maybe we're from very different cultures but it just comes across as a really scummy and horrible thing to do.

Comment: Please cool down, @mattmanser. You've posted some obviously wrong code. I've researched the issue, read the manuals, looked through the source code of the OpenSSL library in question and understood how it works. I've posted the correct function as an answer because there needs to be a correct answer to the question and your code was wrong (my answer was correct from the start, but I've improved it later). I was even nice enough to tell you about errors in your code. I wasn't expecting any praises, but all I got for helping you fix your code were angry attacks. Aren't we here to help people?

Comment: "'My function' is the function you copied and then edited to pretend you didn't." This accusation is obviously wrong. Please refrain from such attack in the future. The function in your answer was `(ceiling(log2(w)) + 7) / 8` and it was incorrect. The function which I posted was `1 + floor(log2(w)) / 8` which is correct (and is rather different from your one). After I've helped you fix your code, you've changed you function to a more correct one - `(ceiling(log2(w + 1)) + 7) / 8`. This can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15314956/revisions. Then you wrote that the manual is wrong.

Comment: "You even copied my function name then changed it to pretend you didn't!" I should be laughing, @mattmanser, but it's sad actually. Yes, I've copied the function signature from your post. And the zero-check too (but, unlike you, I've actually checked what it should return). Does this even matter? I've done it intentionally so that anyone can easily spot what's different. What matters is that I replaced the body of the function from your incorrect function to the correct one.

Comment: Downvoting a correct answer, @mattmanser? I thought too high of you. You really need to read the SO rules instead of waging wars. People who downvote perfectly correct answers are not welcome here. Live and let live. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Combine what WhozCraig in the comments said with this link explaining BN_num_bits:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_num_bytes.html

And you end up with something like this, which should tell you the significant number of bytes:

```
public static int NumberOfBytes(BigInteger bigInt)
{
    if (bigInt == 0)
    {
        return 0; //you need to check what BN_num_bits actually does here as not clear from docs, probably returns 0
    }

    return (int)Math.Ceiling(BigInteger.Log(bigInt + 1, 2) + 7) / 8;
}
```

Comment: This implementation is incorrect. `NumberOfBytes(256)` returns 1 instead of 2. I've posted the correct implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15315250/1497385