# c# equivalent of the c++ "floor" function

Tags: c#, floating-point, int, floor

I'm looking for an implementation of floor(x) in C# so that it would match the C++ version.

```
floor of 2.3 is 2.0
floor of 3.8 is 3.0
floor of -2.3 is -3.0
floor of -3.8 is -4.0
```

Since a C++ reviewer will be checking my code, what implementation of `floor` is reasonable in C# so that he doesn't pull out his (last remaining) hairs?

Comment: Why did you not google `c# floor`?

Comment: @KirkWoll Dumb omission on my part- I went through my browser history and thought I searched for it, but was overwhelmed with [translating this from C++ to C# that I missed that step](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15213853/328397)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Math](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx) class. There are many overloaded form of [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx)

1. [`Math.Floor(Double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx)
2. [`Math.Floor(Decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx)

---

Simple Usage :

```
Math.Floor(2.3) // == 2.0
Math.Floor(3.8) // == 3.0
Math.Floor(-2.3) // == -3.0
Math.Floor(-3.8) // == -4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Math.Floor`. It rounds towards negative infinity, as does the C++ `floor`. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx):

> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding toward negative infinity. In other words, if d is positive, any fractional component is truncated. If d is negative, the presence of any fractional component causes it to be rounded to the smaller integer.

Answer (score 1):

The math library does what you need. Docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). More importantly, the term floor is defined to always behave as you describe. See wikipedia for details on the [mathematical floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties)